# Query of data with an ampersand in it not processing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am executing the following simple query:

```
$result_cat = "SELECT rowid,mgap_ska_id, mgap_ska_record_type, mgap_ska_report_category, SUM(ROUND(mgap_growth,0))+SUM(ROUND(mgap_recovery,0)) AS total
                 FROM mgap_orders
                WHERE mgap_ska_id = '$id'
                  AND (mgap_accept = 1 OR mgap_nr = 3)
                  AND account_manager_id = '" . $_SESSION['account_manager_id'] . "' 
                GROUP BY mgap_ska_report_category";
```

and it works fine on all of my data until it gets to a record that contains an ampersand like this '&' . Te record with this data is set to VARCHAR; is there some reason while the query will not gather only the data containing the & ?

FY: The data is a simple category like this: Soup & Nuts

I dont have any control over the naming conventions as the data is coming from a clients CSV.

Comment: What field contains the ampersand?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it's not working? Exactly what are you expecting and what is happening? If you're outputting HTML, note that `&` is special in HTML and needs to be escaped.

Comment: 'mgap_ska_report_category' is the field and the query isn't outputting any info when it runs.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to display the data? Can you try running the query from the MySQL command line / GUI Tool? I'm guessing it's probably something in how you're displaying it that 'breaks' it.